# Bootstrap checkbox editing border style not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am trying to change the default style of bootstrap checkboxes. I want to add different borders for unchecked, hover and checked. When I try adding a shadow, it works, however border and changing the background color does not work.

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #59A29B;
    background color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Example of it not working. 
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw3gk/2/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this is invalid markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="test">
Option one
</input>
```

This is valid markup:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="test" />
    Option one
</label>
```

Secondly, you cannot style checkboxes this way. See [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Thirdly, you have some invalid CSS properties. `background color` should be `background-color`, but again this will not work (see the link above).

A quick alternative to `border` here would be to use `outline`, but this isn't very desirable:

```css
#test{
    outline: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw3gk/5/).