# Bootstrap 4: customize checkbox border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to customize the color of my checkboxes. I followed the documentation and I came up with a way to change the background:

```
.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-indicator {
        background-color: #ffa500;
}
```

If you click the checkbox there is also a blue border with (I think) a padding around the box itself, but even with some research, I'm unable to find how to change the color of that border too. Anyone can help me? I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfgtgspp/3/) to demonstrate what I have.

Anyone know how to change that border?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is using a `box-shadow` to get this effect:

```
.custom-control-input:focus~.custom-control-indicator {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 3px #0275d8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 3px #0275d8;
}
```

The rounded border is defined with `border-radius`:

```
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-indicator {
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much. Can I ask you how/where you get that from? Because I've searched a few days, without succes. Maybe if you have a secret resource it could help me in the future ;)

Comment: Google Chrome Developer Console (press F12 on your browser). Inspect the item and set the state and you get the CSS rules.

Answer (score 7):

To remove the blue border and reset active state background to #fff in Bootstrap v4.0.0 use:

```
.custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow: none;
}
.custom-control-input:active ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use for a custom border :

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
    #with{
        outline: 1px solid #f00;
    }

#shadow-checkbox{
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="abc" id="with" />
      Option one
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="" id="shadow-checkbox"/>
      Option one
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: If you copy an answer from someone else's contribution please credit them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553310/bootstrap-checkbox-editing-border-style-not-working