# How to remove blue border from the checkbox (bootstrap 4.1)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Bootstrap 4.1**

How to remove blue border from the checkbox which appears on the focus?

[image]

I tried using the outline but it's not working.

The code I'm using is:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

The live version or example is:
https://jsfiddle.net/hussainabid/mgdjprst/

Comment: Try use your browsers dev tool (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome) and see what css is making the border and simply alter it to your liking.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457976/7570485

Comment: These utility classes *might* help: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/shadows/. I haven't checked.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate by the linked question. bootstrap is using `box-shadow` (not `outline`) to create the outline of the checkbox.

Comment: NOT a duplicate indeed

Comment: It *is* a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612852/bootstrap-4-customize-checkbox-border ... see the 2nd answer.

Answer (score 20):

There is a `box-shadow` on the following rule: `.custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before`. You can remove it by adding the following CSS (after Bootstrap CSS):

```
.custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

**Note:** Instead of `!important` you can also [be more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

---

**Example:**

```css
.custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

I don't know why the question was closed by duplicate. This has nothing to do with the `outline` property. Bootstrap add his own outline with `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 0):

The blue border is not defined by standard focus outline. Instead, it is set by bootstrap with a `box-shadow` property you need to override like this

```
.custom-control-input:focus~.custom-control-label::before
{
  box-shadow:none;
}
```